# Payload create Termux terminal using android

Tags: android, terminal, apk, payload, termux

I am using termux terminal in my android.I have create on Payload APK file.It's created but the APK file size 0KB.
Any one Suggestion...??

[image: APK PAYLOAD]
[image: APK 0KB]

Answer (score 0):

First declare that you have installed metasploit and then change your active directory to metasploit by writing `cd metasploit-framework`. 
And then type this command: